# Mongodb keeping consistant order when using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Building a simple chat app, and I'm trying to fetch user messages however the order is not consistent at all when trying to use async.

```
 const msgQuery = await Message.find({ chatId: id }).sort({
    createdAt: 1
  });
  if (msgQuery) {
    msgQuery.forEach(async message => {
      try {
        const postedById = message.postedById;
        const nameQuery = await User.findOne({ _id: postedById }).select({
          name: 1
        });

        console.log(nameQuery.name);

        if (nameQuery) {
          io.to(id).emit(
            'server message',
            postedById === message.userId ? nameQuery.name : 'Other',
            message.text,
            postedById === message.userId ? true : false
          );
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

The result of the message.text is ALWAYS in a random order. I tried not using the nameQuery constant and it worked, order was consistent but.. I need to resolve names too.

Comment: Is the issue that `io.to(id).emit` needs to be called in the order that `msgQuery` is in?

Comment: Yes, I've managed to find a fix.. I am not fetching the names, creating an object each time, pushing that object into an array in a specific order and then looping through it while getting the names.. Code:       let message = new Object();
            message.text = db_message.text;
            message.userId = db_message.userId;
            message.postedById = db_message.postedById;
            message.entId = db_message.entId;
            message.createdAt = db_message.createdAt;
            messages.push(message);

Comment: Try using `Promise.all` instead, this is the sort of situation it's for

Comment: `forEach(async ...)` is antipattern. To process concurrently, use Promise.all. To process sequentially, use `for..of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guarantee the order that the `async` functions will complete. Rather than emit inside of the `async` function, you have to wait for *all* of the async functions to complete and then emit in order. I think the simplest way to do this would be to use `Promise.all` with `.map`. You can also probably optimize this by only querying for user names that you haven't already found -- store them in an object or something like that.

```
const messages = await Promise.all(msgQuery.map(async message => {
  /* query code */

  if (nameQuery) {
    return {
      postedByName,
      message: message.text,
      postedByUser,
    };
  }
}));

messages.filter(Boolean).forEach(({ postedByName, message, postedByUser }) => {
  io.to(id).emit(
    'server message',
    postedByName,
    message,
    postedByUser,
  });
});
```

The `messages` array will retain the message order, it will just wait until all of the user queries have completed.